# Is it OK to say '"an earlier way to do something"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I want to describe a method that can help achieve some goal earlier than conventional method. Is it OK to say "an earlier way to do something"?

Comment: Not an earlier way, but a faster or quicker or more efficient way.

Comment: @Xanne But I want to emphasize that this method can do things "earlier" than conventional way. Can "faster" address that?

Comment: I think you want “sooner” rather than earlier, then,

Comment: "Faster" does indicate that you will get the result sooner (earlier) than you would using a slower method.

Comment: @smwikipedia *A way that produces an **earlier** result is …* The problem isn't with the use of the word *earlier* but with the construction of the phrase it's in. (Even there, it's not the most common phrasing.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Could you suggest a better way to describe that?

Comment: @smwikipedia You have to provide at least one complete sentence, if not—ideally—several sentences, for actual context. All of the suggestions of *faster* and *sooner* are being suggested because they likely are better in any context I can think of.

Comment: This question suggests that you are learning English as a non-native speaker. You may not be aware of the existence of [ell.se] which I think would be a more appropriate place to post.